# Is there a way to trace the reason 'fseventsd' process hogs CPU?

Tags: snow-leopard

I run Mac OSX 10.6 and noticed that a process 'fseventsd' was taking 100% CPU and 1.5G RAM. Doing a google search, I found that this could be tied to Time Machine. 
However, I do not run Time Machine on this computer.

Is there a way to trace the source of the resource hog? Does it log to anywhere? A restart 'fixed' the issue, but I'm sure it will come back if I can't figure out why it began in the first place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find the source? We're experiencing the same issue on our snow leopard server. I may try a reboot but I can't do that until later tonight.

Comment: I have not had it pop up since my reboot, (un)fortunately, so I still don't know the source

Comment: I have the same problem. Rebooting doesn't help. After 20 to 30 minutes, fseventsd starts again to take 99% CPU. The Macbook is not silent anymore...

Answer (score 7):

fseventd is the filesystem event logging process, you can read a lot about it in the ars technica review of Mac OS X Leopard. You can use programs like [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) to see the same kind of output it sees.

From the article:

> The FSEvents framework relies on a
>   single, constantly running daemon
>   process called fseventsd that reads
>   from /dev/fsevents and writes the
>   events to log files on disk (stored in
>   a .fseventsd directory at the root of
>   the volume the events are for). That's
>   it. That's the super-high-tech
>   solution: just write the events to a
>   log file. Boring, pragmatic, but quite
>   effective.

You can check that log though I dont know how useful it will be for you. I would not be that surprised to see Time Machine, which deals with many files, and sometimes many many tiny files, to possibly cause some issues with fsevents.

Comment: Hopefully it's not Time Machine, since this is disabled! Anyway, I'm reading up on fseventer, so thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Either one program was stuck in a very efficient loop writing changes that caused `fseventsd` to have a lot of work or it's an infinite loop itself processing an unresolvable data structure on one of the mounted volumes.

In the prior case - programs like fseventer that read the same stream of data will likely hang as well - you'll now have two processes at 50% utilization trying to process an infinite amount of data. (This is a great data point if you are poking to see what's amiss.) It's analagous to  questions asking why `syslogd` is taking all the CPU - usually it's some other program gone nuts causing it a lot of work.

When/if it happens again - start quitting programs and consider logging out. You will know if the offending item is a system level process or a user level process. `fs_usage` might be useful to see what specific programs are IO heavy.

`fsck` from a boot into single user mode is usually required if you have circular hard links or other degenerate file system shenanigans that can cause this sort of spike in activity.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I was being unclear, you definitely could not open fseventer while the poop proverbially hit the fan. I just meant more to give you an inkling into what kind of data was logged and viewable, as fs_usage would.

Comment: I loved learning about fseventer - look very nice. There is no failure - just data.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the tip on 'fs_usage'. And yeah, I figured it wasn't actually fseventsd causing the load, but rather some other program. I expect a loop somewhere. As an aside, machine has been running normal load for 24 hours or so, and it hasn't happened again.